# how to get rid of TASM warning Operand size conflict

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

When compiling the following assembly source file TASM 4.1 (`tasm file.asm`):

```
ideal
p386n
model flat
stack 100h  ; Dummy, to pacify TASM.
codeseg
start: cmp bx, after-start
after:
db 66h, 81h, 0fbh
dw after-start
end start  ; Dummy, to pacify TASM.
```

, I get the following warning:

```
Turbo Assembler  Version 4.1  Copyright (c) 1988, 1996 Borland International

Assembling file:   file.asm
*Warning* file.asm(6) Operand size conflict
Error messages:    None
Warning messages:  1
Passes:            1
Remaining memory:  470k
```

How do I get rid of warning *Operand size conflict* in line 6 (`start: cmp bx, after-start`)?

I have a workaround: hardcoding the bytes of the `cmp bx, ...` instruction with `db`. Is there anything better?

Comment: I think the syntax you are looking for in ideal mode to force that expression to 16-bits is `cmp bx, small after-start`

Comment: You might want to use `/M2` to force 2 passes when assembling when using forward references. It can generate smaller code in some cases.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: `/M2` (and even smaller: `/M999`) does indeed generate shorter code because of multiple passes, but it doesn't get rid of the warning.

Comment: My comment about `/M2` was separate from the warning message.  The reason I noted it is that you may have noticed that the `cmp` with 1 pass takes up 4 bytes with a single `NOP` after, where as with multiple passes the `cmp` is reduced to just the 4 bytes with no trailing `NOP`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comment by **Michael Petch**, I've just verified that using `cmp bx, small after-start` does indeed get rid of the warning.

```
ideal
p386n
model flat
stack 100h  ; Dummy, to pacify TASM.
codeseg
start: cmp bx, small after-start
after:
db 66h, 81h, 0fbh
dw after-start
end start  ; Dummy, to pacify TASM.
```